# Using multiple nested _GET variables in a single URL

Tags: php, image-processing, get

**Setup:**

- Script that generates word images from multiple letter images
  (autotext.php)
- URL is formatted:
  `www.whatever.com/autotext.php?text=hello%20world`
- Script that alters images server-side to run filters or generate
  smaller sizes (thumbnail.php)
- URL is formatted:
  `www.whatever.com/thumbnail.php?src=whatever.png&h=XXX&w=XXX`

**Use-case:**

I want to generate a smaller version of the autotext server-side.  So my call would look something like:

`www.whatever.com/thumbnail.php?src=autotext.php?text=hello%20world&h=XXX&w=XXX`

As you can see, I would like to treat a URL with _GET variables as a variable itself.  No amount of playing with URI encoding has helped make this work.

I have access to the PHP for both scripts, and can make some simple alterations if that's the only solution.  Any help or advice would be appreciated.  I would not even rule out a Javascript frontend solution, though my preference is to utilize the two scripts I already have implemented.

Comment: Yes, URL encoding *would* help. Show whatever you've tried to patch the `src` parameter together.

Comment: you want an **&** between vars on the url after the first **?**

Comment: can you paste what your current code/implementation looks like?

Comment: @mario The URL I've tried is in my question above.  What else can I show you that would be of assistance?

Comment: @Dagon There are actually two ? because one is using a URL as its variable.  Hence the complication I'm running into.

Comment: @STLMikey Since this is a URL formatting issue, I'm not sure what code you would like to see.  The autotext and thumbnail scripts are extensive (I didn't develop them), but they work as described above.  I haven't made any alterations to them yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by urlencoding all the $_GET params into a variable then assigning that variable to another, like this (untested):

```
// Url generation
$url = www.whatever.com/thumbnail.php?src=(urlencode(http_build_query($_GET)));
```

Then you should be able to retrieve on other side:

```
$src = urldecode(explode('&', $_GET['src']));
```

I've seen this exact behavior when trapping where to redirect a user, after an action occurs.

**---- Update ----**

Your "use case" url was correct:

```
www.whatever.com/thumbnail.php?src=autotext.php?text=hello%20world&h=XXX&w=XXX
```

.... except that you CANNOT have more than one ? within a "valid" url. So if you convert the 2nd ? to a &, you should then be able to access `$_GET['text']` from the autotext.php script, then you can urldecode it to get the contents.

Comment: Thanks for the potetial approach, Mike.  Unfortunately I can't quite unravel your suggestion.  I'm unclear what should happen with the $src string, since it's never called in your $url generation statement.

I read the php documentation on http_build_query(), urlencode(), and urldecode(), but I'm no closer to understanding why you're using them in this example, nor why it would make the code work.  Could you perhaps break it down a little further?

And a massive THANK YOU for even taking the time to help in the first place!